# Linking dependencies between PCL and Xamarin app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, dependencies

While working on my Xamarin cross-platform app I am using native apps and a PCL for shared code.
Unfortunately it does not seem possible for me to link the dependencies properly in my PCL.

For example: I use a bouncycastle DLL / dependency in my PCL. When I reference the PCL to my android / iOS app it requires me to link the same dependency / dll again, just inside the native project.

So now I have two dependencies in my native app which seems redundant:

**NativeApp**:

- *PCL*
- *BouncyCastle*

Is it possible that I only need the BC reference in the PCL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCLs use .NET portable (a subset of the whole .NET library) while standard libraries use the full .NET library Becaue of that PCLs cannot reference standard .NET Libraries because they use two different sets of .NET.

On top of that PCLs define the target platforms it is going to support. You can see this in the properties > Library > Targeting of your PCL.

PCLs can only reference libraries that are also PCLs that contain a collection of targets that contain ALL of the targets the PCL has itself.

If you want to make another library for your PCL to reference, make it a PCL itself  and make sure it has all the same targets than the PCL that is going to reference it.